# Creating multiple dataframes using multiple column values & name them accordingly

Tags: python

I want to create multiple dataframes based on 2 columns namely :

```
Col1    Col2
  Fr         DK
 Fr      IE
  Fr    IE
  Fr    SE
  Fr    SE
  Fr    SE
  Po    DK
  Po    IE
  Po    IE
  Po    SE
  Po    SE
  Po    SE
  Hk    DK
  Hk    IE
  Hk    IE
  Hk    SE
  Hk    SE
  Hk    SE
  Hk    DK
  Hk    IE
```

I need dataframes based on a combination of col1 & col2 namely

```
df_1

Col1    Col2
  Fr         DK

df_2

Col1    Col2
  Fr         IE
  Fr         IE
```

& so on ..

How can it be done ?

I was using the following :

```
#create unique list of names
 UniqueNames = ["Fr","Po"]

#create a data frame dictionary to store your data frames
DataFrameDict = {elem : pd.DataFrame for elem in UniqueNames}

for key in DataFrameDict.keys():
    DataFrameDict[key] = df[:][df.col2 == key]
```

But this lets me do only based on 1 column. How do I do it using multiple columns & how do I refer them ?

I get a dataframe 
    DataFrameDict["Fr"]

[image]

However , I wanted seperate dataframes to be created based on col1 & col2. Is there a way I can pass the loop by setting up a dictionary as follows :

```
UniqueNames = {col1:["Fr","Po"],
               col2:["IE","SE"]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't really clearly stated, so I'm not sure what your criterion is for splitting the dataframes. If you just want each row to be a separate dataframe, go with this

```
all_dfs = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    curr_df = pd.DataFrame(row)
    all_dfs += [curr_df]
```